# Change lat long coordinates to xy on a grid

Tags: c#, graphics, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I receive lat,long coordinates from the GPS of my vehicle and the coordinates of another object near the vehicle. What I want to do is to draw(using Graphics) points using those coordinates but as xys. My car would be the center so(0,0). My problem is with the object and how could I calculate its xy. I have a picturebox(556,536).

```
public struct XY
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
};

XY carPoint;
XY objPoint;
string incomming = Convert.ToString(spl.ReadLine());
carText.x = incomming.Substring(0, incomming.IndexOf("="));
carText.y = incomming.Substring(incomming.IndexOf("=") + 1,incomming.IndexOf("_") - incomming.IndexOf("=") - 1);
objText.x = incomming.Substring(incomming.IndexOf("_") + 1, incomming.IndexOf("*") - incomming.IndexOf("_") - 1);
objText.y = incomming.Substring(incomming.IndexOf("*") + 1, incomming.IndexOf("/") - incomming.IndexOf("*") - 1);
carPoint.x = float.Parse(carText.x);
carPoint.y = float.Parse(carText.y);
objPoint.x = float.Parse(objText.x);
objPoint.y = float.Parse(objText.y);
interPoint.x = float.Parse(interText.x);
interPoint.y = float.Parse(interText.y);
```

This is how I receive the coordinates, but I couldn't test with anything to solve my problem as I found none.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I mean, depending on how far away the object is you can ignore curvature of the earth and simply do (`latObj-latCar`, `longObj-longCar`). But really, this is very much a "give me the code" question and will likely be closed. Show us some code you've written and explain why it doesn't work, and how it should work.

Comment: I just edited, thanks for reminding.